# JSF & Primefaces & IE Ajax does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, internet-explorer-9

I am using JSF Mojarra 2.2.1 , Primefaces 4.0 Snapshot and IE 9. This problem happens in IE 9 and also a similar problem exists when I replace it with f:ajax unless I render using @all. When command button is rendered via ajax request, it fires a normal request in the following request. I created a simple code to illustrate the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="testForm">
        <h1>Test of IE9 Ajax</h1>
        Text: <h:outputText value="#{testBean.count}" />
        <br />
        <p:commandButton oncomplete="alert('a')" update=":testForm"
            action="#{testBean.increment}" value="click me">
        </p:commandButton>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

And my bean is,

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int count = 0;

    public void increment()
    {
        count++;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

}
```

In the test, alert is given on only at odd numbers which is an other indicator of ajax call is not made smoothly.

Update:

I realized this is happening because IE9 ignores inputs' onclick="javascript" events when they are replaced jquery's replace all method.

Update 2:

This does not happen in my home computer IE 9 (same version), it happens only in office computer. I cannot see security settings, Do you know why this happens? Javascript works but does not function properly.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: sometimes, this problem is due to primefaces's jar,try another version of primefaces,may it will work,also check IE console to know the issue

Comment: Changing to 2 older primefaces vers did not work, the interesting thing is that it renders following script for button click event but it executes script in first click and does not execute in the second click.  Script : onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'testForm:j_idt7',update:'testForm',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){alert('a');}});return false;"

Comment: can you try without a colon i.e.,update="testForm" ?

Comment: nope, It did not work.

Comment: have you tried it in another browser? If it doesn't work in another browser, can you give us what the browser error console says?

Comment: It does not happen in firefox 22 and ie 10. Console says nothing, I think it is all about how IE 9 handles dynamic added input elements by JSF or Primefaces.

Comment: PF 4 is currently in alpha stage (it's only available as snapshot which you've got to build yourself). This problem is clearly a bug in PF 4. As being an alpha tester, it's your responsibility to report this issue to them. We can't do much for you here. Or, if you actually didn't intend to test it, but to *use* it, then you shouldn't be using an alpha version if you want stable software.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I am going to use the last stable version. If you read my updates, the problem is about my work computer's IE settings (which I cant see all of them remote, I need to ask IT), it also does not work smooth when I drop off prime faces and use jsf ajax although javascript is enabled.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. I'd start clearing browser cache.

Comment: Maybe ActiveX is disabled on your office IE. I think it is not possible to check that without having access to the security settings. If you can get access check "Security">"Internet">"Custom Level">"ActiveX controls and plug-ins" in the "Internet Options">"Security" tab of the IE.

Comment: what if you change action="#{testBean.increment}"  to actionListener?

Comment: +1  I'm also seeing these issues like ajax stuff not working in IE. After trying to debug my own app, I just tried Primefaces showcase & to my surprise even their showcase isn't working correctly for ajax stuff on IE 10! (not using compatibility mode in IE).

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear but I read somewhere support for IE in PrimeFaces is not very good and even being discontinued. Could be just versions of IE below 10. Sadly computers at work are IE8! I put in a browser detect and have users download Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Hi there, I have this problem Random en IE9 & IE10, did you found a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code inside the `<h:head>` tag:

```
<f:facet name="first">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</f:facet>
```

Let's me know if it help.

Answer (score 0):

Resetted the security settings of the browser (IE 11) resolved the issue in my case. Unfortunately, I don't know which setting is responsible for this.

Comment: I don't understand why I had to rewrite the answer several times until it wasn't automatically rejected any more due to qualify requirements that were not mentioned, but claimed not to be met.